# How to use ListView without Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Often,we use `ListView` with `BaseAdapter`. But I study adapter pattern these days.I want to know if we can use `ListView` without Adapter? For example, we can write the items in the `ListView`,Just like this:

```
<ListView>
        <Item/>
        <Item/>
        <Item/>
</ListView>
```

I have tried many times, but it doesn't work. Can I use `ListView` without  any`Adapter`?

Comment: no,  you have to use the adapter

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

In string.xml do this first..

```
   <string-array name="Entries">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 3</item>
   </string-array>
```

Then do this in your ListView in xml..

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/Entries"></ListView>
```

Comment: NOTE: this is just an illusion that there is no adapter being used. using entries user an adapter internally

Answer (score 2):

`ListViews` **MUST** use an `Adapter`. If you don't set an `Adapter` and set the `android:entries` via XML then internally it will use an adapter in order to inflate views.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html):

> `ListView` is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items. The list items are automatically inserted to the list using an `Adapter` that pulls content from a source such as an array or database query and converts each item result into a view that's placed into the list.

[`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) class is the child class of [`AdapterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) and by the definition:

> An AdapterView is a view whose children are determined by an `Adapter`.

Hence `Listview` must use an `Adapter` in order to inflate its child views.